# ubuntu 14.04 remove ibus but system setting disappear

Tags: 14.04, ibus, fcitx

I used to remove ibus and install fcitx for typing Chinese.But this time when I remove ibus ,it automaticly remove these things
`ibus ibus-table ubuntu-desktop unity-control-center
  unity-control-center-signon webaccounts-extension-common xul-ext-webaccounts`
how can I remove ibus only?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and you can install **gcin**.

> sudo apt-get install gcin

Or simply desable ibus on **Language Support** set it to **none**.